# Was Hakim Luqman a prophet?

Tags: prophets, islamic-notability

Quran mentioned Hakim Luqman for his wisdom. Does Hakim Luqman was a prophet of his time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit textual evidence about prophethood being given to him, within the Quran or Hadith. Most exegetes held that he was a saint and not a prophet, however some have held that he was a prophet. The same is the case with Dhul Qarnayn, Khidr, Maryam and some other personalities mentioned in the Quran.

**Ref:**

> ولهذا كان جمهور السلف على أنه لم يكن نبيا
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura31-aya12.html) - see also [[English Translation]](https://ia801907.us.archive.org/12/items/tafsir-ibn-kathir-10.-Volumes/Tafsir_Ibn_Kathir_Vol._7.pdf#page=574)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @umh for explaining with reference.